# Yii2 multiple orFilterWhere

Tags: php, activerecord, filter, yii2

I am working on a dynamic search module in yii2 and todays task is to create the filter for lists. For example Dropdown lists where you can select multiple conditions. In our case it is a state of a car. So you can select if a car is Active or Inactive or Sold. But there is a scenario where the user wants to search both. 
The filter works well if you search only the state of the car, it generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `gepkocsi` WHERE (((`allapot`='A')) OR ((`allapot`='F'))) AND (`torolt` IS NULL) LIMIT 20
```

It works because there aren't any further condition like licence plate. Now lets se what happens if we add that condition into our search. 
So at this time we search for cars where the licence plat contain the i letter and the status is Active or Saled. The following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT * FROM `gepkocsi` WHERE (((`rendszam` LIKE '%i%') OR ((`allapot`='A'))) OR ((`allapot`='E'))) AND (`torolt` IS NULL) LIMIT 20
```

The problem is that after the licence plate (rendszam) shuold be a AND insted of OR. This is generated by the following method. And this leads us to the main source of the problem.

```
/**
 * @param $fieldName
 */
public function filterList($fieldName) {
    if (isset($fieldName) && !empty($this->$fieldName)) {
        foreach ($this->$fieldName as $singleFieldName) {
            $this->query->orFilterWhere(['or',
                [$fieldName => $singleFieldName]]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think if I add separatly all the fieldnames as a parameter of orFilterWhere it should work. What do you think what is the best practice to do it? Or Yii2 has someting magical to do that?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution how to append all the OR conditions. Simply the Yii2 generates an IN caluse.

```
/**
 * @param $fieldName
 */
public function filterList($fieldName) {
    if (isset($fieldName) && !empty($this->$fieldName)) {
        //$this->debug($this->$fieldName);
        $tomb = [];
        foreach ($this->$fieldName as $singleFieldName) {

            $tomb[$fieldName][] = $singleFieldName;

        }
        $this->query->andFilterWhere($tomb);
    }
}
```